# Adding Null Value to ComboBox bound to ArrayList

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle

I've seen a few similar questions to this issue I'm having, but they all don't seem to work out.

I currently have a method that populates an arraylist with items from a database query, and then returns the arraylist to be used to populate a ComboBox. The ComboBox will be used as a search filter for additional database queries.

I'd like to add a null value to the arraylist in order to allow for the user to "turn the filter off" when the null value is selected.

The issue comes up when adding the null value to the array list. When I add the null value before the database items are added, all of the items don't show up in the actual ComboBox. When I add the null value after the ArrayList has been populated, the null value never shows up as a row in the ComboBox, but everything else is there.

```
        public static ArrayList DropDown()
    {
        ArrayList status = new ArrayList();
        connect.Open();

        // Finds the stuff to use in the  COMBO BOX
        cmd.CommandText = String.Format("query");
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {

            status.Add(String.Format("{0}", reader[BANK_ID]));
        }
        string holder = null;
        status.Add(holder); 
        connect.Close();
        return status;
    }
```

This results in the populated ComboBox, but no null row.

```
        public static ArrayList DropDown()
    {
        ArrayList status = new ArrayList();
        string holder = null;
        status.Add(holder); 
        connect.Open();

        // Finds the stuff to use in the  COMBO BOX
        cmd.CommandText = String.Format("query");
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ;
        while (reader.Read())
        {

            status.Add(String.Format("{0}", reader[BANK_ID]));
        }

        connect.Close();
        return status;
    }
```

This results in nothing in the combo box.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you thought about adding the string "null" to the combo box?  Then when you are using the combo box as the search criteria, replace your string value of "null" to the sql value of null.  Be aware of '=' vs 'is' in Sql Server.  Gets me everytime ( '= null' doesn't work)

Comment: Just clear your ArrayList before adding null.

Comment: Does it still show same behavior if you create your ArrayList manually, without querying the database?

Comment: The same behaviour does occur when the arraylist is created manually. Also, I'm not sure how clearing the arraylist before adding null would help. I did it anyways, but same result =/. I'd rather not resort to using the string null and casting it unless I absolutely have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The items collection of a combobox can not contain null. Refer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.add.aspx

I assume setting `DataSource` is internally checking for this and hence the behavior that you have noted (probably a more informed person can confirm this)

I suggest you add String.Empty instead and you can get rid of arraylist all together and use a string array/list instead.

```
comboBox.Items.Insert(0, string.Empty);
```

Comment: Ahhh That makes more sense... Thanks for the help!